# SWITCH in SSRS - nesting

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I am reporting a date value in a table - Month(fields!date.Value) - and the values are coming through numerically - 1 for January, 12 for December, etc.

Is it possible to use SWICH to convert these to "January" when 1, "February" when 2, etc ? If so, how can I nest this within the expression above - Month(Fieds!Date.value)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try =MonthName(Month(fields!date.Value)).

Comment: Thanks - I appreciate the prompt response.